# incompatible generic return type

Tags: java, generics

I understand generics pretty well, but came across a seemingly simple problem that I don't quite understand. Take a look at the following example.

```
public <T extends Object> T getSetting(String settingName) {
    return settings.getJsonObject(settingName).getValue("value");
}
```

`settings` is a instance attribute from type `vertx.core.json.JsonObject`. The result of `getValue` is `Object`.

I thought by setting the return type to `T` I would be able to return any type that is `Object` or an super type like `String` or `Integer`. This code however gives me the following error message.

> incompatible types: `java.lang.Object` cannot be converted to `T`

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: What if `T` is `Integer` and `getValue()` returns a `String`?

Comment: I understand that technically a mismatch can happen. But in practice that won't happen because the type of every setting is know by the programmer. What is my best solution here?

Comment: Use an unsafe cast: `return (T)...`

Comment: FYI, `<T extends Object>` is exactly equivalent to `<T>`, since every generic type extends `Object`.

Comment: Your question implied that you don't understand why you're getting an error. From your comment it sounds like you do understand but are seeking a workaround. Which is it?

Comment: I know `<T extends Object>` and `<T>` are the same, but I find `<T extends Object>` more self explanatory and cleaner. To answer you other question, both are the case. I realized the problem after reading your first comment.

Comment: It's very unusual practice to specify an upper bound unnecessarily. I would strongly caution you to follow industry standards rather than what may feel intuitive to you in the moment, unless you never expect anyone (including yourself) to have to maintain the code in the future.

Comment: “*But in practice that won't happen because the type of every setting is know by the programmer*” is a nonsensical reasoning. If you know that a value has a certain type, you insert a type cast to document that confidence. Generics is a tool for letting the compiler check the correctness of type assumptions; you should not abuse it to pretend such a safety at places where the compiler actually has no chance of checking the correctness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code does not compile because whatever T is, decided at compilation time, does not need to match what `getValue` will return which is determined at run-time 
which is not restricted at all.

You can add a `(T)` cast and that would transform the error in a warning but that would not prevent the potential run-time cast error and that is why it stays as a warning.

I don't think there is any real workaround for this as you can never be certain of the type of the `getValue` return ... however you can provide some methods that at least would:

a. fail more gracefully (with a nicer error message),

b. return a default value if the type is not the one expected,

c. give the user the chance to provide the casting lambda to transform
   any possible input type into the expected return value class.

E.g.

```
public <T> T getSetting(String settingName, Class<T> clazz) {
    final Object obj = settings.getJsonObject(settingName).getValue("value");
    if (obj == null)
       return null;
    else if (!clazz.isInstance(obj))
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("wrong setting class; was expecting %s but found %s", clazz.getSimpleName(), obj.getClass().getName());
    else {
       return clazz.cast(obj);
    }
}
...
Integer x = getSetting("mysetting", Integer.class);
```

Or:

```
public <T> T getSetting(String settingName, Function<Object, T> cast) {
    final Object obj = settings.getJsonObject(settingName).getValue("value");
    return obj == null ? null : cast.apply(obj);
}
...
Integer x = getSetting("mysetting", o -> Integer.parseInt(o.toString()));
```